# Can you only earn the "Mortarboard" badge once?

Tags: support, badges

I looked through the list of users who have been awarded this medal but I didn't see a name twice. Can you only earn this badge once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - the mortarboard badge is awarded the first time you earn 200 reputation and can only be earned once.